# てえな attached to verb stem

Tags: conjugations, colloquial-language

Hello fellow inquisitors of Japanese. In my classroom today - in Balamb Gardens of course - my students and I were gleefully reading through Shiwon Miura's latest novel あの家に暮らす四人の女 when we - to our great  befuddlement I must add - encountered the following sentence:

> 稼いで、いい車乗って、いい女抱き**てえな**と身の内をたぎらせていたのか。

The problem you see is the てえな. We were unable to ascertain its meaning, despite burrowing through several dictionaries.

Any ideas on what it means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ～てえ is an informal, masculine version of ～たい, "want to~~".
たい is a 助動詞. The な is a 終助詞(sentence-ending particle).

You can parse the sentence this way:

> 「稼いで、いい車(に)乗って、いい女(を)抱きてえな。」と身の内をたぎらせていたのか。

---

Example:

> 食いたい --> 食いてえ (食いてぇ、食いてー)
>   結婚したい --> 結婚してえ (結婚してぇ、結婚してー)

Compare:

> 知らない --> 知らねえ (知らねぇ、知らねー)
>   うるさい --> うるせえ (うるせぇ、うるせー)

Comment: Probably related... http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29099/changing-of-diphthongs-at-the-end-of-words-to-%E3%81%88-in-exclamations

Answer (score 2):

This is a kind of vowel transform.
"ai" sometimes changes to "e" or "ee".
Other vowel translation:
"ou" -> "u" or "oo"
"てえ" is often used by male, but you should not use this in public.

Comment: "ou" -> "u" or "oo" >> Can you give some examples please?