# Meaning of "ねーし"

Tags: meaning

What does "ねーし" mean? For example: 笑ってねーし！

Answer (score 6, accepted):

～ねーし　＜＞　～ねえし　＜＞　～ないし

笑ってねーし would be a colloquial way of saying "I didn't laugh!" A more standard way of saying it would be 笑ってないし。

The elongation(ー) after ね means to elongate the sound of the previous letter (hence ねえ above). The ねー is the colloquial form of ない。 The し is another (normally colloquial) letter usually used to list things. In this instance however, its use is at the end of a rebuttal to an inquisition or accusation.

> A: 何{なん}でトムとメールしないの？
>
> A: Why haven't you emailed Tom?
>
> B: だって彼{かれ}のメールアドレス知{し}らないし！
>
> B: Because, I don't know his email address!

Similar colloquial words can be found in this similar question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29099/changing-of-diphthongs-at-the-end-of-words-to-%E3%81%88-in-exclamations/29103#29103).

Comment: 形容動詞・名詞なら「～だし」(eg きれいだし, 鉛筆だし)、形容詞・動詞・形容詞型助動詞(ない、たい)なら「～し」(eg 大きいし, 食べるし, 食べないし) になると思います・・・たぶん。

Comment: @choco なるほど！んじゃ、「its use is identical to だし」って書き直したほうがいいよね？