# What grammatical form is "食わねえ。" using, and what does it mean?

Tags: grammar

> 食わねえ。

I didn't understand the above sentence. What is this "ねえ" and why is "食べる" in the form of "食わ"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ねえ is a colloquial form of ～ない (see [Pronouncing ない as ねい / ねえ (also ~oi to ~ei)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41395/78)).

And here, the verb is [食]{く}う, not 食べる.  食う is a "more" "familiar" word for eating.

So you can see that the negative form is 食わない, and the ねえ makes it super slangy.