# Is くだらねぇ verb conjugation?

Tags: verbs, slang, informal

From the first episode of Death Note:

> まったく くだらねえ

Is くだらねえ slang for くだらない?

Comment: `くだない` -- You meant to type くだ**ら**ない?

Comment: Yeah, another typo. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[くだらない](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)⇒くだらねえ

[Changing of vowels at the end of words to え](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29099/30454)

[Meaning of "ねーし"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29292/30454)

[Pronouncing ない as ねい / ねえ (also ~oi to ~ei)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41395/30454)

Comment: This is hardly an answer, though it is helpful.

Comment: @jarmanso7 I understand how you may think it is too short, but this answer actually directly answers the question asked also demonstrates one important SE policy: answers should not go in the comments. I couldn't have commented with the info but I didn't.

Comment: Well it's not about the length, it's about the fact that it is a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). I agree with the SE policy that answers should not go in the comments.

Comment: @jarmanso7 Well, I appreciate the criticism, but I do think saying it is a link-only answer is inaccurate and unfair, and to be honest, a distortion of the facts. I showed the word inflection which is exactly what the questioner asked. I felt unqualified to explain the cultural and historical aspects of that change, so I linked much existing great answers. To say "it's a link-only answer" is just ignoring the question and ignoring my first line.

Comment: Okay, besides the 4 links, you included a single word (without an explanation), and therefore it's not a link-only answer. Still, it lacks context and explanation, which is one of the reasons why link-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: I mean, how is "くだらない⇒くだらねえ" better than "Yes, くだらねえ is one form for くだらない", to answer OP's question?

Comment: You are not required to improve your answer if you don't feel like, or don't have time, but the answer could definitely be improved, so don't get surprised I criticise it.