# what is the meaning of 悪ぃ

Tags: expressions, slang

I have come across this a few times when reading: 悪ぃ(わりぃ).

I have seen it used as an expression and as an adj.
from the context it looks like it carries a meaning of "sorry" or "my bad".
is this a different dialect or shorter form of 悪い(わるい), or does it have some other significance?

Comment: From my experience it is exactly as you describe it. A condensed form of warui, which would mean a very casual "my bad".

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3752/5010 http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29099/5010 http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/5010

Comment: Where abouts did you come across it? If it was Manga, then this is largely a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 4):

るい ー＞ りい is simply a linguistic transformation which occurs in the speech of Tokyoites, when I myself hear it I imagine it to come from a young male.

悪ぃ is simply another way to say 悪い and is not specific to the meaning of "My bad," although is can just as equally take this meaning in the right circumstance.

For example in the following contexts

https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E6%82%AA%E3%81%83
https://twitter.com/hashtag/%E6%B0%97%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A1%E6%82%AA%E3%81%83

It is simply being used as a linguistic variation of 悪い.

Comment: Hang on, is it to be understood that 悪ぃ is unambiguously pronounced as わりい? If so, I should take note of this.

Comment: @NickOveracker 悪ぃ is always pronounced わりい but わりい is not always written 悪ぃ. As it is a colloquial way of pronouncing it is really up to interpretation how to spell it. As of the typing of this comment, on google [悪ぃ](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E6%82%AA%E3%81%83&oq=%E6%82%AA%E3%81%83&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2j69i60j0.191j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has 5,260,000 results while [悪りい](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%E6%82%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%84&oq=%E6%82%AA%E3%82%8A%E3%81%84&aqs=chrome..69i57.143j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) has 998,000.