# くれぇ in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, words

> 膝の調子は悪くても、ハシゴ**くれぇ**は押さえられるだろ？！

I'm guessing this is some kind of shorter version of something else?

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29103/9831

Comment: It's くらい........

Comment: My question was not about the different versions of pronouncing a word but anyway.. Right, くらい. Didn't think of that.