# What does うめーな mean here?

Tags: words

The sentence in question is 恵那はやっぱうめーなー. This is from Yotsuba manga chapter 8 and the English translation is "Ena-Chan's good at this after all." I believe that やっぱ means too/also/likewise and from the English translation I would think that うめーなー would mean good. If it helps at all, the previous sentence was よつばはいまいぞ. I didn't understand what いまい meant but the English translation also said good for いまい. Could うめーなー be slang for some work that means good or perhaps mean "the same"?

Comment: Perhaps the word is うまい but pronounced differently.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29099/changing-of-diphthongs-at-the-end-of-words-to-%e3%81%88-in-exclamations/29103#29103

Comment: Judging from your last couple of questions, there seems to be something wrong with your book/website.  いまい makes no sense.  うまい does.

Comment: Yea I'm starting to think the same. I've avoided asking some questions where I've assumed that that were some issues but at times I get the feeling that something may be "slangy" and actually written correctly. I'll try and refrain from posting these type of things in the future unless it's obvious that the grammar/vocab is correct.