# Don't understand 歌うめぇ meaning

Tags: translation, meaning

I'm a bit stuck in translating  歌うめぇ. I found somewhere that めぇ can be a colloqiual form of まい, but I don't know if it is true. Could you help me, please?

The context is that you've heard someone singing who didn't do it for a while.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3746/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29099/9831