# What is the meaning of バカにはええじゃないか?

Tags: grammar, translation, colloquial-language, spoken-language

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to interpret ばかにはええじゃねえか in the manga here. I believe ばかにはええじゃねえか = ばかにはいいじゃないか　but I still can't make sense of this. As the picture suggests, the father says this as some sort of a greeting for the boy who's just got back from school. My best effort at translating this is something like "Aren't you look wonderful!" (my dictionary says ばかにいい =　be mighty nice; be absolutely wonderful). But it's obvious that the boy is dejected, so my translation can't be right.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18458/9831 (See: `/ai/ > /ee/`, so は**やい** →は**ええ** , **ない**か → **ねえ**か / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13073/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/29103/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3752/9831

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it might be "バカにはやいじゃないか", where "はええ" is a twisted pronunciation of "はやい". And the sentence means "(You came back) very early, didn't you"

Comment: That's right! I totally missed it.

Answer (score 1):

ばかにはええ＝ばかに早い、ということです。
「はええ」は、はやいがくずれた（なまった）ものです。

Answer (score 1):

the meaning is similar to いつもより(帰り)はやいじゃないか→oo, you back so(much) earlier than usual